# Jquery is listed at top of head, but refuses to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I'm trying to include JQuery into my electron project, and it should be working right now. But it doesn't. My  is as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Esteam</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/node-waves/dist/waves.min.css" />

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="wintools.js"></script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
```

Now, as you can see, I reference JQuery long before any script is called, and it is being loaded by electron shell, but I find myself at the error code `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. None of the other pages on stackoverflow have helped me, because jquery is already referenced before the other scripts and I copied the script tag directly from google. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what line of code is triggering it. Do you need to import jquery into your module. `import $ from 'jquery'`?

Comment: Oh, sorry then. Nothing came up in google for me when searching for electron

Comment: @Craicerjack the very first line in the code, $(document).ready...